# How to change tabindex of all button inside a div using class

Tags: javascript

I want to set tabindex for all button inside a div my structure is like this.

```
<div class="content">
  <div> <button name="first" /> </div>
  <div> <button name="second" /> </div>
  <div> <button name="third" /> </div>
<div>
```

I am trying it with below code:

```
const content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
const kbButtons = content[0].getElementsByTagName("button");
kbButtons.map( (elem,index) => { elem.setAttribute("tabindex", '-1') })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) method returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), and not an array. Since it's not an array, it doesn't have the `Array.map()` method. In addition, map is used to transform an array to a new array, not for side effects (this is the purpose of `forEach()`).

Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get an [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of all buttons which are descendants of `.content`, and then iterate them with [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), and set the tab index:

```js
const kbButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.content button')
  .forEach(elem => {
    elem.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1')
  })
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div><button name="first">first</button></div>
  <div><button name="second">second</button></div>
  <div><button name="third">third</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".content button");
for(var i=0; i<btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].setAttribute("tabindex", '-1');
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div> <button name="first" /> </div>
  <div> <button name="second" /> </div>
  <div> <button name="third" /> </div>
<div>
```